How can I display an image on a Waveshare ILI9486?
I am using STM32 and 3.5 inch TFT display (Waveshare ILI9486) and I want to display an image and I have connected the SD card. How to do using the Arduino IDE?
For now I am trying to fetch a word from a text file and trying to display on the LCD.
#include <SPI.h>
#include <SD.h>
#include <Adafruit_GFX.h>
#include <Waveshare_ILI9486.h>

#define SD_MOSI_PIN PC12 //MOSI Pin
#define SD_MISO_PIN PC11 //MISO Pin
#define SD_SCLK_PIN PC10 //Clock Pin
#define SD_SS_PIN PB6 //Chip Select or Slave Select Pin


//#define SD_CS_PIN PB0
#define TFT_CS_PIN  PB6
#define TFT_DC_PIN PA8
#define TFT_RST_PIN PA9

#define  BLACK   0x0000
#define BLUE    0x001F
#define RED     0xF800
#define GREEN   0x07E0
#define CYAN    0x07FF
#define MAGENTA 0xF81F
#define YELLOW  0xFFE0
#define WHITE   0xFFFF


#define BUFFER_SIZE 50

char textBuffer[BUFFER_SIZE];

// Assuming the constructor in your library takes no arguments
Waveshare_ILI9486 tft; 
uint16_t color565(uint8_t r, uint8_t g, uint8_t b) 
{
  return ((r & 0xF8) << 8) | ((g & 0xFC) << 3) | (b >> 3);
}

static int bufferIndex = 0;
File myFile;
HardwareSerial SerialPrint(PC5, PC4);
/*  void setup()
  {
    Serial.begin(115200);
    Serial.println("Initializing SD card...");
    SPI.setMISO(SD_MISO_PIN);
    SPI.setMOSI(SD_MOSI_PIN);
    SPI.setSCLK(SD_SCLK_PIN);

      SPI.begin();
      tft.begin(); // Assuming the library's begin function doesn't require arguments

    if (!SD.begin(SD_SS_PIN))
    {
      //SerialPrint.println("SD card Initialization failed!");
      Serial.println("SD card Initialization failed!");
      while (1);
    }
      //SerialPrint.println("SD Card Initialization done.");
       Serial.println("SD Card Initialization done.!");

       myFile = SD.open("test5.txt", FILE_READ);
  
}


void clearBuffer() {
  for (int i = 0; i < BUFFER_SIZE; i++) {
    textBuffer[i] = 0; // Set all characters to null terminator (0)
  }
  bufferIndex = 0; // Reset the buffer index
}



void loop() 
{ 
  if ( myFile.available())
  {
    char nextChar = myFile.read();

     
     while (nextChar >=0 && bufferIndex < BUFFER_SIZE)
     {
      textBuffer[bufferIndex] = nextChar;
      Serial.println(textBuffer);
      Serial.println(bufferIndex++);
      nextChar = myFile.read();
  
    }
    
    Serial.println(textBuffer);
    Serial.println(bufferIndex);
    Serial.println(sizeof(textBuffer));

    // Check for buffer overflow and handle it (optional)
   if (bufferIndex >= sizeof(textBuffer)) 
    {
      
       clearBuffer();
    }
 
  }
 else 
{
    // Display the content of the buffer on the LCD
    tft.fillScreen(BLUE);  // Clear the screen before displaying text
   tft.setTextSize(2);
   tft.print(textBuffer);
   bufferIndex = 0;  // Reset buffer index for next file read
  myFile.close();    // Close the file after reading
  }
 delay(1200); // Adjust delay based on desired reading speed
  
  
}*/


what is the problem that you are trying to solve? ... the code you presented does not compile ... please update it

You are using PB6 as the chip select for both SD Card and  TFT. For SPI communication, if you have two devices connecting to the same SPI bus, you need one CS pin for each device.

You have to use the image2LCD software. Link is given in the software section here: https://www.waveshare.com/wiki/3.5inch_TFT_Touch_Shield
